# .NET Generic Set?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections, set

Is there a generic container implementing the 'set' behaviour in .NET?

I know I could just use a `Dictionary<T, Object>` (and possibly add `nulls` as values), because its keys act as a set, but I was curious if there's something ready-made.

Comment: Last time I checked, in Java, HashSet<T> is implemented with HashMap<T, Object> <=> Dictionary<T, Object> (with null in values) but in .NET, HashSet<T> doesn't use any Collection. It's a "core" implementation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`HashSet<T>` in .NET 3.5

Answer (score 3):

I use the Iesi.Collections. namespace that comes with NHibernate (docs [here](http://monogis.org/monogis_doc/html/Iesi.Collections.html)) - maybe worth considering if you are in .NET < 3.5

Answer (score 2):

Introduced in .NET 3.5:  [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (see below).

Introduced in .NET 4.0: [`ISet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081.aspx):

> Provides the base interface for the abstraction of sets. This
>   interface provides methods for implementing sets, which are
>   collections that have unique elements and specific operations.

The interface has two implementations in the .NET 4+ BCL:

- [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx):

  > ...provides high performance set operations. A set is a collection that
  >   contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no
  >   particular order
- [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx):

  > Represents a collection of objects that is maintained in sorted order.
  >   A SortedSet(Of T) maintains a sorted order as elements are inserted
  >   and deleted without affecting performance. Duplicate elements are not
  >   allowed.

FWIW: There's also an **`internal`** `class TreeSet<T>: SortedSet<T>` under the namespace `System.Collections.Generic`.
Its only purpose seems to be the usage in the implementation of [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx).